# Anime where everyone hates people who can't use magic

Tags: story-identification, anime, magic

I saw a short few months ago on YouTube where a guy was being tortured by nurses because he can't use magic. He is naked, then suddenly a girl comes and falls on his man part.

When he was naked other nurses were around him but they were wearing clothes and they weren't doing anything dirty. He was in a chair but I don't remember if they tied him up or not.

This anime was set in modern times.

Comment: Ah yes, the venerable "Oops, I fell and impaled myself on your man part... well, since I'm here, I'd might as well move up and down" anime trope.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - You'd be surprised how often that happens. In '*Carry On...*' films

Comment: YouTube's search history is broken I remember the title had magic in it but now if I search in history I can't find it it's same for other videos too

Comment: It seems that YouTube is actively breaking basic functionality in order to force people to subscribe just to get it to work.

Comment: My exams are over two days ago now I am looking for  animes to watch I remembered that scene I am keep on searching guy getting tortured by nurses because he can't use magic or  guy getting experimented  because he can't use magic  in YouTube and Google but that scene doesn't show up maybe it's not a popular anime

Comment: Does [Mahaurabo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QvBJeGcNdM) look familiar? Kazuki can use magic, but only eight times in his life, and poking around the wiki, medical experimentation on him is done. Oh, and because a prophecy says he will father a great magician, at least three of his fellow students are trying to breed with him...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - That's why anime was a mistake.